# Weak convergence and convergence of inner product implies strong convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $H$ be a real Hilbert space and assume that

$$ u_{n} \rightharpoonup u \textrm{ in } H, $$

$$ v_{n} \rightharpoonup v \textrm{ in } H $$
and

$$ \langle u_{n},v_{n}\rangle \rightarrow \langle u,v \rangle \textrm{ in } \mathbb{R}. $$

Is it then the case that $u_{n} \rightarrow u$ and $v_{n} \rightarrow v$ strongly in $H$?

**EDIT** Consider $\langle u, v \rangle > 0$

Comment: A fact that might be helpful: if $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ and $||u_n|| \rightarrow ||u||$ in $\mathbb{R}$, then $u_n \rightarrow u$ strongly in $H$.

Comment: @kkc Yes, I know this result, however even if I write $\langle u_{n} - u,  v_{n} - v\rangle \rightarrow 0$, what assure us that $u_{n} \rightarrow w_{1}$ and $v_{n}\rightarrow w_{2}$? Moreover, can I have $\langle w_{1} -u, w_{2} -v \rangle$ with $w_{1} \neq u$ and $w_{2} \neq v$?

Comment: I see $v_{n}\rightharpoonup u$. Is it a typo? Should it be $v_{n}\rightharpoonup v$?

Comment: Note that the additional requirement $\langle u,v\rangle > 0$ can always be satisfied by adding, e.g., any nonzero vector to the sequences $u_n$ and $v_n$. My favorite question for examinations in functional analysis was: "Is there a sequence $u_n$ with $u_n \rightharpoonup u$, $u_n \not\to u$ and $u \ne 0$?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Here is a counter-example. Consider the real Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}=l^{2}(\mathbb{N})$.
Let $a\in\mathcal{H}$ be defined by $a(n)=\frac{1}{n}$. Note that
$||a||^{2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}<\infty$ and $a\neq0$.
For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $e_{n}\in\mathcal{H}$ be defined
by $e_{n}(k)=\delta_{nk}$. Let $x=y=a$, $x_{n}=e_{n}+a$, $y_{n}=e_{n+1}+a$.
We go to show that $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ weakly, $y_{n}\rightarrow y$
weakly, $\langle x_{n},y_{n}\rangle\rightarrow\langle x,y\rangle$,
$||x_{n}-x||\not\rightarrow0$ and $||y_{n}-y||\not\rightarrow0$,
$\langle x,y\rangle>0$.

Proof:

1. Clearly $\langle x,y\rangle=||a||^{2}>0$.
2. Let $u\in\mathbb{H}$ be arbitrary, then $\langle x_{n}-x,u\rangle=\langle e_{n},u\rangle\rightarrow0$
   as $n\rightarrow\infty$. This shows that $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ weakly.
   Similarly, we can show that $y_{n}\rightarrow y$ weakly.
3. $\langle x_{n},y_{n}\rangle=||a||^{2}+\langle a,e_{n}\rangle+\langle a,e_{n+1}\rangle\rightarrow||a||^{2}=\langle x,y\rangle$.
4. $||x_{n}-x||=||e_{n}||=1$, so $||x_{n}-x||\not\rightarrow0$.
   Similarly, $||y_{n}-y||=||e_{n+1}||=1$, so $||y_{n}-y||\not\rightarrow0$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the reason why $\langle e_{n} ,u \rangle$ goes to zero.

Comment: Write $u=(u(1),u(2),\ldots)$, then $||u||^{2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u(n)^{2}<\infty$,
which implies that $u(n)\rightarrow0$. (The general term of a convergent
series must converge to zero).

Now $\langle u,e_{n}\rangle=u(n)\rightarrow0$.

Comment: Of course. Thank you for the time and explanation.

Comment: You could have chosen $x_n=e_n$ and $y_n=e_{n+1}$ from the beginning (i.e., $a=0$)

Comment: No. If we set $x_{n}=e_{n}$ and $y_{n}=e_{n+1}$, then $x_{n}\rightarrow0$
weakly and $y_{n}\rightarrow0$ weakly. That is, $x=y=0$. However,
it is required that $\langle x,y\rangle\neq0$.

Answer (score 2):

No. For example, if $v_{n}=v=0$, then we always have $v_{n}\rightharpoonup v$
and $\langle u_{n},v_{n}\rangle\rightarrow\langle u,v\rangle=0$.
If your proposition is true, it implies that $u_{n}\rightarrow u$
whenever $u_{n}\rightharpoonup u$, which is obviously false.

Comment: I got it. But, apart from this case, what do you say?

Comment: I see $v_{n}\rightharpoonup u$. Is it a typo? Should it be $v_{n}\rightharpoonup v$?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I edited my answer.